# Rails controller RSpec undefined method `encode' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got a Rails 6 app with an ActiveAdmin panel which has a method of creating CSV files with admin activities logs. I want to create RSpec test for that action like below:

`admin/users_spec.rb`

```
describe Admin::UsersController, type: :controller do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  before { sign_in admin }

  let!(:admin) { create(:admin_user) }

  describe '#import_csv' do
    let(:csv_admin_log_generator_instance) { instance_double(::AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator) }

    before do
      allow(::AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator).to receive(:new).and_return(csv_admin_log_generator_instance)
      allow(csv_admin_log_generator_instance).to receive(:call)
      get :index
    end

    it 'accepts send_data' do
      get :import_csv
      expect(csv_admin_log_generator_instance).to receive(send_data)
    end
  end
end
```

But it gives me an error:

```
  1) Admin::UsersController#import_csv accepts send_data
     Failure/Error:
       send_data file.encode('UTF-8'), type: 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8; header=present',
                                       disposition: 'attachment; filename=admin_logs.csv'

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `encode' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is a method which I want to test (it behaves like a controller).

```
  collection_action :import_csv, method: :get do
    file = ::AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator.new.call

    send_data file.encode('UTF-8'), type: 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8; header=present',
                                    disposition: 'attachment; filename=admin_logs.csv'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here `allow(csv_admin_log_generator_instance).to receive(:call)` you stub this method and the result of it is nil. You need to force it to call the original method `allow(csv_admin_log_generator_instance).to receive(:call).and_call_original`

Comment: Nope, I'm getting an error: `<InstanceDouble(AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator) (anonymous)> is a pure test double. 'and_call_original' is only available on a partial double.`

Comment: Try to replace `let(:csv_admin_log_generator_instance) { instance_double(::AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator) }` by `let(:csv_admin_log_generator_instance) { ::AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator.new }`

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting an error: `Failure/Error: expect(csv_admin_log_generator_instance).to receive(send_data)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method 'send_data' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdminUsersController::ImportCsv:0x00007fd6cd4597e0>`

Comment: This is another kind of error. You misprinted a method name `send_data` should be `:send_data` with a colon at the beginning. Also, you expect `csv_admin_log_generator_instance` to receive `send_data`, but `send_data` is a method of a controller not `::AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator`

Comment: Ok so how to test such action? If I change expect to be like: `expect(controller).to receive(:send_data)` I'm getting massive error ending with: `expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments`

Comment: I think you need to treat this controller as a black box and don't test internally behaviour. I'd prepare data for CSV and then check the result `expect(response.body).to eq(expeced_csv_data)`. Take a look at this guide https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/testing-your-activeadmin-controllers-with-rspec

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I don't need to mock any of those methods but just simply enable paper_trail gem and update specs as follows.

```
describe Admin::UsersController, type: :controller do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  let!(:admin) { create(:admin_user) }
  before do
    sign_in admin
    get :index
  end

  it_behaves_like 'controller response status', 200

  describe '#import_csv' do
    it_behaves_like 'controller response status', 200

    it 'create CSV file', versioning: true do
      admin.update!(email: 'steven.hyde@example.com')
      get :import_csv
      expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to include 'text/csv'
    end
  end
end
```